# How to assign variables from layers?

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, tf.keras

im training a net for predicting a length 257 output vector. what i wanna do is refeed my predictions back to my input on the fly. therefore i want to stack my output vectors to a 2d array and concatenate this to my input as sort of a second image channel.

I just dont get how i can store my output predictions in a sort of global accessable tensor on which i can do some further calculations. So far i tried something with tf.Variable and tf.assign / tf.make_array on my output but didnt get any further.
Any help would be highly appreciated. I'm using TF 1.14

Comment: Are you using `GradientTape` or `model.fit`?

Comment: Im using model.fit . I'm now trying a workaround with train_on_batch followed by predict on batch but i dont know if this is sufficient. can i combine these two?

Comment: The method you mentioned is the only way I know when using `model.fit`.